# Include CSS and Javascript in my django template

Tags: javascript, css, django

I am a newbie in Django 1.5 and I have learn some basic things about it. My problem is , I am not able to include css and javascript in my template. I have read the documentation about it but as i have said. I am a newbie and i can't understand it clearly. Please help me know the step by step procedure to a include css and javascript in my base.djhtml template. Thanks.

This is my settings.py

```
    # Django settings for myweblab project.

    DEBUG = True
    TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

    import os.path
    PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)

    ADMINS = (
        # ('Your Name', 'your_email@example.com'),
    )

    MANAGERS = ADMINS

    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
            'NAME': 'myweblabdev',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
            # The following settings are not used with sqlite3:
            'USER': '',
            'PASSWORD': '',
            'HOST': '',                      # Empty for localhost through domain sockets or '127.0.0.1' for localhost through TCP.
            'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default.
        }
    }

    # Hosts/domain names that are valid for this site; required if DEBUG is False
    # See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts
    ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

    # Local time zone for this installation. Choices can be found here:
    # http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name
    # although not all choices may be available on all operating systems.
    # In a Windows environment this must be set to your system time zone.
    TIME_ZONE = 'America/Chicago'

    # Language code for this installation. All choices can be found here:
    # http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html
    LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

    SITE_ID = 1

    # If you set this to False, Django will make some optimizations so as not
    # to load the internationalization machinery.
    USE_I18N = True

    # If you set this to False, Django will not format dates, numbers and
    # calendars according to the current locale.
    USE_L10N = True

    # If you set this to False, Django will not use timezone-aware datetimes.
    USE_TZ = True

    # Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.
    # Example: "/var/www/example.com/media/"
    MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'media')

    # URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
    # trailing slash.
    # Examples: "http://example.com/media/", "http://media.example.com/"
    MEDIA_URL = 'http://localhost:8000/media/'

    # Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
    # Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
    # in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
    # Example: "/var/www/example.com/static/"
    STATIC_ROOT = ''

    # URL prefix for static files.
    # Example: "http://example.com/static/", "http://static.example.com/"
    STATIC_URL = '/static/'

    # Additional locations of static files
    CURRENT_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)).decode('utf-8'))

    STATICFILES_DIRS = (
        os.path.join(CURRENT_PATH, 'media'),
        # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
        # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
        # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    )


    # List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
    # various locations.
    STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
        'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    #    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
    )

    # Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.
    SECRET_KEY = '1k38*$@ig616^xg#hy=n+yz-e9))s@_x-uq1pp%6xh!89m_r9('

    # List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
    TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
        'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
        'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
    #     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
    )

    MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
        'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
        # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
        # 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    )

    ROOT_URLCONF = 'myweblab.urls'

    # Python dotted path to the WSGI application used by Django's runserver.
    WSGI_APPLICATION = 'myweblab.wsgi.application'

    TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
        os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'templates')
        # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
        # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
        # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    )

    INSTALLED_APPS = (
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.sites',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
        # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
         'django.contrib.admin',
        # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
        # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
    )

    # A sample logging configuration. The only tangible logging
    # performed by this configuration is to send an email to
    # the site admins on every HTTP 500 error when DEBUG=False.
    # See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging for
    # more details on how to customize your logging configuration.
    LOGGING = {
        'version': 1,
        'disable_existing_loggers': False,
        'filters': {
            'require_debug_false': {
                '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
            }
        },
        'handlers': {
            'mail_admins': {
                'level': 'ERROR',
                'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
                'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
            }
        },
        'loggers': {
            'django.request': {
                'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
                'level': 'ERROR',
                'propagate': True,
            },
        }
    }
```

this is my url.py

```
    from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
    from django.conf import settings
    from myweblab.views import index

    # Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
    from django.contrib import admin
    admin.autodiscover()

    urlpatterns = patterns('',
        # Examples:
        # url(r'^$', 'myweblab.views.home', name='home'),
        # url(r'^myweblab/', include('myweblab.foo.urls')),

        # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
        # url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

        # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
         url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
         url(r'^$', index, name="index"),

    )

    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.STATIC_URL, 'show_indexes': True}),
    )
```

and my base.djhtml

```
    <!DOCTYPE >
    <html>
        <head>
            <!-- css and javascript template should be here -->
            <title>
                {% block title %}
                {% endblock %}
            </title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/style.css" />
            <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
            {% block content %}
            {% endblock %}
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: What does your template code look like?

Comment: nothing is failing yet, i just do not have an idea how would i include css and javascript in my template

Comment: <!DOCTYPE >
<html>
 <head>
  <!-- css and javascript template should be here -->
  <title>
   {% block title %}
   {% endblock %}
  </title>
 </head>
 <body>
  {% block content %}
  {% endblock %}
 </body>
</html>

Comment: If you're struggling with HTML you should go learn it before attempting a Django project.

Comment: the problem is i do not know what will be the path of my stylesheets, my stylesheets is under my media folder

Comment: the stylesheets must be in your static folder

Comment: Here is a [tutorial](https://www.dev2qa.com/how-to-use-static-css-js-files-in-django/)

Answer (score 59):

First, create **staticfiles** folder. Inside that folder create css, js, and img folder.

**settings.py**

```
import os

PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
         'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', 
         'NAME': os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'myweblabdev.sqlite'),                        
         'USER': '',
         'PASSWORD': '',
         'HOST': '',                      
         'PORT': '',                     
    }
}

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'media')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static')

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'staticfiles'),
)
```

main **urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from myweblab import settings

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    .......
) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

**template**

```
{% load static %}

<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">
```

Comment: what does admin.autodiscover() do?

Comment: @py_ios_dev https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.autodiscover

Answer (score 17):

Refer [django docs on static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/).

In **settings.py**:

```
import os
CURRENT_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__).decode('utf-8'))

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(CURRENT_PATH, 'media')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

STATIC_ROOT = 'static/'

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
                    os.path.join(CURRENT_PATH, 'static'),
)
```

Then place your **js** and **css** files **static** folder in your project. **Not in media folder.**

In **views.py**:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, RequestContext

def view_name(request):
    #your stuff goes here
    return render_to_response('template.html', locals(), context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

In **template.html**:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/style.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
```

In **urls.py**:

```
from django.conf import settings
urlpatterns += patterns('',
    url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True}),
)
```

Project file structure can be found [here in imgbin](http://imgbin.org/index.php?page=image&id=12245).

Comment: what will be int he url.py? when i try to view the source code and click the media/css/style.css it says file not found

Comment: I have updated my answer. But it should work without this. Can you post your `STATIC_ROOT`, `STATIC_URL` and `STATICFILES_DIRS` settings and make sure that `'django.contrib.staticfiles',` is included in your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting?

Comment: I have updated the question please check my files thanks

Comment: Can you post your project's file structure also? Also `MEDIA_ROOT` and `STATICFILES_DIRS` should not point to same folder. Change any one of them.

Comment: hi this is my file structure image http://neumerance.webs.com/filestructure.png

Answer (score 3):

Read this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/:

> For local development, if you are using runserver or adding
>   staticfiles_urlpatterns to your URLconf, you’re done with the setup –
>   your static files will **automatically** be served at the default (for
>   newly created projects) STATIC_URL of /static/.

And try:

```
~/tmp$ django-admin.py startproject myprj
~/tmp$ cd myprj/
~/tmp/myprj$ chmod a+x manage.py
~/tmp/myprj$ ./manage.py startapp myapp
```

Then add `'myapp'` to `INSTALLED_APPS` (`myprj/settings.py`).

```
~/tmp/myprj$ cd myapp/
~/tmp/myprj/myapp$ mkdir static
~/tmp/myprj/myapp$ echo 'alert("hello!");' > static/hello.js
~/tmp/myprj/myapp$ mkdir templates
~/tmp/myprj/myapp$ echo '<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}hello.js"></script>' > templates/hello.html
```

Edit `myprj/urls.py`:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

class HelloView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "hello.html"

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', HelloView.as_view(), name='hello'),
)
```

And run it:

```
~/tmp/myprj/myapp$ cd ..
~/tmp/myprj$ ./manage.py runserver
```

It works!