# Javascript development workflow in django

Tags: javascript, css, django, workflow

I am working on a project with django + some js + some css. Is there a place where i should put the dev version of the js/css source files that are compiled into js/css prod versions (and stored in /static) ?

Comment: Possible duplicate for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491727/include-css-and-javascript-in-my-django-template

Comment: I know how to render static css/js files with Django. But where should I put the dev js/css files ? Is there any specific Django folder for that ? 'Cause putting them in static means that they're accessible from the client which is not desirable.

Answer (score 0):

You can go this way:

In settings:

```
LIB_URL = '/var/static/lib/'
```

Make new context_processor:

```
from django.conf import settings


def static(request):
     return {'LIB_URL': settings.LIB_URL}
```

add new context processor to `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` and then in template:

script:

```
<script src='{{ LIB_URL }}jquery/jquery.js'></script>
```

And make folder `/var/static/lib/`, download your dev libs here. Think that'll help you.