# Can't attach css files or image to Django template

Tags: django

Surfing the internet, I found some solutions of my problem. But it didn't help([Include CSS and Javascript in my django template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491727/include-css-and-javascript-in-my-django-template)) last answer.
I added this in `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns += patterns('',
    url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True}),
)
```

This is my `settings.py`:

```
CURRENT_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__).decode('utf-8'))

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(CURRENT_PATH, 'media')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

STATIC_ROOT = 'static/'

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
                    os.path.join(CURRENT_PATH, 'static'),
)
```

And my template:

```
<html>

<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/main.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/font-awesome.min" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
{% load staticfiles %}
<div id="modal" class="modal fade">
            <div class="modal-header">
                    <div>Вхід у систему</div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form action = "/login/" method="post">
                <div>
                    <label for="username">Логін:</label>
                    {{form.username}}
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="password">Пароль:</label>
                    {{form.password}}
                </div>
                <br>
                <div>
                    <input type="submit"  value="Submit">
                </div>
                </form>
            </div>
       </div>


<img src="{{STATIC_URL}}ukraine.png" alt="My image"/>
</body>
</html>
```

As the result CSS files are not working and even image isn't found.
I created folder for static files: `D:\KIT\static\css`

Comment: Try changing `CURRENT_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))`

Answer (score 0):

Referring from official [documents](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/):

1. Make sure you have included `django.contrib.staticfiles` in `INSTALLED_APPS`
2. What is the `CURRENT_PATH`? Make sure it is `D:\KIT\`
3. Then you can inlcude them like this:

   ```
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "css/main.css" %}" />
   ```
4. Make sure your templates start with `{% load staticfiles %}`

Comment: Dont forget {% load staticfiles %}

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot to run collectstatic. It's  highly unpractical to run it everytime something changed while in development, so to avoid this you have to modify your settings.

Add django.contrib.staticfiles to your INSTALLED_APPS and set DEBUG=True, runserver will then do the heavy lifting for you.

I would also recommend using the static template tag {% static 'path/to/static.css' %} over {{ STATIC_URL }} and placing templatetag loading on the first line (second line if you're extending your template) of your template file.