# Bootstrap's navbar doesn't work

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap

Currently I am learning Django framework, I've decided to get familiar with it by making a simple Blog app, but I've problem with navigation bar, I'm trying to make a responsive navbar, with collapse classes etc. I've searched about this problem in this forum, but nothing helped, so I need personal help if possible. That's my code, please note that I did include bootstrap and bootstrap's javascript plugin. Thanks in advance.
How this navbar works: http://scr.hu/28mo/ncxtp

```
<div class="navbar-wrapper">
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">MyBlogName</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id ="navbar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
            </ul>

        </div>

    </div>

</nav>
</div>
```

Comment: do you see any 404 in the console ? Also, would it be possible to reproduce your error in a fiddle ?

Comment: there is no any error occuring, I'll do a screenshot and paste it how it looks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collapse needs some [Javascript to work properly](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse). You should add it to your template. Quick and dirty with script tags in your posted template. Later read about [staticfiles](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/staticfiles/) and how to ship them with your app. There is also a quite useful example here: [Include CSS and Javascript in my django template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491727/include-css-and-javascript-in-my-django-template)

Comment: But I said that I have included bootstrap's javascript.

Comment: sorry - and you made sure it is loaded properly in your browser using its development tools?

Comment: By following line **<scriptsrc="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>**

Comment: can you ensure that this file is properly loaded using your browsers development tools?

Comment: How I can prove it?

Comment: In chromium hit `F12` -> navigate to `sources` and have a look what is loaded - also checkout the tab `console` for errors.

Comment: Okey, I'll check it, but is navbar made properly?